# Angular 2 canActivate : retrieve value in component

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I get the value of the canActivate param of the routing from inside the component ?

```
{
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] // => This one
}
```

I'm asking that because I would like to show/hide elements in the template, depending the user is connected or not.

So, for now, I'm calling the authentication service inside the component but then it makes two calls, one from the guard, the other from the component.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.canAccess().then(
        auth => this.canAccess = auth
    );
}
```

Is there a way to subscribe to some routing event and get the value of the canActivate property ?

Comment: Why are you using a guard if the user can access the page even if he's not authenticated?

Comment: because I want to hide the navigation bar, which is common to all pages

Comment: So why can't you just use something like `*ngIf="canAccess"` applied to the navigation bar?

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing but this is not the point. I want to fill the canAccess variable from the route, not from the service because I make two calls to the server, which is not great

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use resolver? It won't initiate component until some data is fetched

```
{
    path: 'path',
    component: SomeComponent,
    resolve: {someVarYouNeed: someResolver}
}

class someResolver implements Resolve

constructor (private service: MyService) {
    return service.getData.map(data => data.json())
}
```

in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.varYouNeed = this.route.snapshot.data['someVarYouNeed'];
}
```

Remember that resolver should return Observable and data from this Observable is attached to route data as property according to name used in resolver in routes

Comment: what's the type of `this.route` ? I tried Route but it's not found in @angular/rotuer

Comment: Found it, it's `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: If you find my answer helpful please mark it, it will genuinely boost my ego! :)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry but it's not solving my problem. I just need to retrieve the content of the Guard from the app.component, not adding a resolve to each route. But maybe it's just impossible

Comment: But I didn't know about the resolver, which is cool because I could use it for other purpose. Upvote !